# insert mongob script while making container

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose file bring.yml

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.18
    hostname: mongods
    depends_on:
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 64005:27017 # Host:Container

  mongoprovision:
    image: mongo:4.4.18
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "sleep 2 && mongo --host mongods:27017 /tmp/client-key.js && mongo --host mongods:27017 /tmp/tis-provision.js" ] # 'tistest' is the db name. Should match with tisservice_cfg file configuration->db->name
    volumes:
      - ../../resources/mongodb/client-key.js:/tmp/client-key.js
      - ../../resources/mongodb/tis-provision.js:/tmp/tis-provision.js # Script to provision the DB
```

and i have client-key.js and tis-provision.js file respectively

```
var documents = [
    { "clientid": "tisclient001" },
    { "clientid": "tisclient002" },
    { "clientid": "tisclient003" },
    { "clientid": "tisclient004" }
];

printjson(documents);

db.tis.client.key.Data.insertMany(documents);
var doc = {
"trafficInfluenceID": "10",
    "applicationFunctionId": "device",
    "applicationId": "Virtual_Reality_Arena",
    "region": "south",
    "zone": "north-zone",
    "userId": {
    "UEIdentityType": "IPAddress",
        "UEIdentity": "UEflow"
},
    "state": "ordered",
    "trafficFilters": [
    {
        "flowId": 0,
        "flowDescriptions": "10.98.0.0/24 5060"
    }

],
    "notificationUri": "notifyuri",
    "notificationAuthToken": "notifyauthtoken"

};
printjson(doc);
db.tis.trafficinfluence.Data.insertOne(doc);
```

and config file is

```
  db: # DB configurations
    name: tistest                # name of the mongodb
    url: mongodb://mongods:27017 # a valid URL of the mongodb
```

After run command `docker-compose -f bring.yml`, the mongodb container is built but inside the container there is no name tistest and no collections are there I want to made the tistest automatically when the container is made and script data is automatically inserted.